# Nuxt 3 Slow Middleware

Tags: javascript, performance, nuxt.js, middleware, nuxt3

The auth processes I do in Middleware work, but they work very slowly, for example, I log in and I am directed to the homepage, then I make it go to the login location in the url part, but because I am logged in, the rate should not be displayed, but first it shows the login, then it returns to the homepage, normally it should not show the login, how can I prevent this.

```js
import {getAuth, onAuthStateChanged} from "firebase/auth";
import {userCollection} from "\~/store/userCollection";
import {useRouter} from "#app";

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async(to,from) =\> {
  const auth = getAuth();
  await onAuthStateChanged(auth,  (user) =\> {
    if (process.client){
      if (user && to.path.startsWith('/login')){
        userCollection().setCurrentUser({displayName :user.displayName, email: user.email});
        useRouter().push('/');
      }
      if (!user && !to.path.startsWith('/login')){
        userCollection().setCurrentUser(null);
        useRouter().push('/login');
      }
    }
  });

})
```

The difference with the nuxt-link tag is that when I try to go to the login, navigateTo throws the login and does not return. With useRouter, it does not send even though I do not press login. It works better than navigateTo. The only problem is that when I type login to the url, it first shows the login and returns to the homepage.